# Configure ASP.NET application to use two authentication methods?

Tags: asp.net, iis, authentication, forms-authentication, windows-authentication

I am new to ASP.NET development and moreover I am only extending an existing application which i did not create.

I have a working ASP.NET application which uses "Forms authentication" throughout all its pages. I have added a new webservice in a subfolder "webservices\Dummy.asmx". This webservice works fine but because it should be called by an external application which can't authenticate through a form, i need to enable "Integrated Windows Authentication (Basic Authentication or Digest Authentication)" ONLY for the subfolder "webservices".

I tried to configure it in IIS but it did not work.
So that i can set a different authentication method i have to create the folder "webservices" as an "Application". But if i do so then my function stops working with the error "Could not create type 'Dummy'."

Is it possible to have one web application and to authentication methods ?
If yes how is it configured in IIS ?

Or what would be the better way if i need ONLY one page (webservice) to use a different authentication then the rest of my application.

Thank you in advance for any information.

Bye

PS: I use Windows 2008 Server and the app runs on .NET Framwork 2.0

Answer (score 1):

> I tried to configure it in IIS but it
>   did not work. So that i can set a
>   different authentication method i have
>   to create the folder "webservices" as
>   an "Application". But if i do so then
>   my function stops working with the
>   error "Could not create type 'Dummy'."

This is the correct way. Can you explain the problem you are having here ? What is dummy ?

> Mixing Forms and Windows Security in
>   ASP.NET
>   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972958.aspx

Comment: When i create a new "Application" from my folder "webservice" then the file Dummy.asmx in this folder starts throwing an error. (Before that it worked fine.) 
The error is:
Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: Could not create type 'Dummy'.
Line 1:  <%@ WebService Language="vb" Codebehind="Dummy.asmx.vb" Class="Dummy" %>

Dummy=only an example name of my webservice

Comment: Maybe the problem is somewhere else.
Can it be that once i create the new "application" then my Dummy.asmx looses the connection to the main DLL in the bin-folder and won't work anymore ?
I am really a newbie here :-(((

Comment: Try creating the bin directory under "webservice" folder and putting the DLL there after you convert to application.

Comment: It works !
I have copied the whole "bin"-directory under the "webservice"-directory. And now i have two different authentication-methods. One for the main application, the other for the "webservices" application.
Thanks a lot. I am now one step further. :-)

Comment: However it really does not look very clean.
I would not really want to have two complete sets of DLL-directorie in one web.
Is there a "cleaner" solution ?
Can i somehow reference my bin-directory which is "one level" above ?
Or how about a symlink. That could work.
Or maybe i should not try to do this "add-on" inside this application at all and rather create a completely separate application in a new folder and copy the DLLs there.
What would you suggest ?

Comment: Well, it depends a lot more on the complete picture you are trying to achieve. I would suggest read quick tutorial on asp.net to get started:http://www.asp.net/get-started

Comment: Thank you for your help.
Will try to figure it out.
Bye

Answer (score 0):

Web services that live in a larger application often do not need to be protected.  If that's acceptable in your scenario, you can use a standard web.config construct to allow anonymous access to the service while still protecting the rest of the application.

Add a `location` node to the main `configuration` node that defines the rules for just the web service:

```
<location path="webservices\Dummy.asmx">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <!-- this overrides the parent app protection rules -->
            <allow users="*" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```